# Is separate employee table and employee login table needed

Tags: database

I have built a payroll system for some company and it works properly. The problem is I don't have much knowledge about databases. I prepared an employee table and an employee login table separately. These both table have employeeID, username, email columns. Only the login table has a password field. I did that because one of my friend said it is the correct way to do that. But I have my doubts now. So please help me to understand which way is the correct way to store password.

Are separate tables needed or can we store the password in the main employee table?

Comment: Why do you need password in a payroll system? Passwords should be kept securely in your LDAP directory.

Comment: You should try to understand `Database Normalization` , get a basic grasp of it.

Comment: @seva titov using this system employee can view their attendance  , bonus they have got and few information

Comment: @mane yes i am learning them these days. but still i have to practice more

Answer (score 0):

Two tables are reasonable as long as you've done your normalization.  The login table would need a user ID (employeeID, presumably) and the (salted and hashed) password, and the random salt you use when hashing the password — but probably not the username and definitely not the email column.  You might want to add columns to record when the password was last changed and when it may next be changed and when it expires.

The other table is fine as it stands.  It would not be out of the question to combine the two tables into one.  It might be sensible to have the username in the same table as the password, in which case the employee table would lose the username column.  You want to avoid repetition — if you have the username in two tables, you open up the possibility that Employee ID 100 has username 'poweruser' in the Employee table and username 'intern' in the Employee Login table — which is unlikely to be desirable.

One advantage of separating them is that you can put more stringent permissions on the password table so most users can't even read the password table.  You use special software to control access to it and update the password.

Note that you do not risk storing the raw password.  You must hash it (preferably multiple times) and you must hash it with a random salt (which should be unique and at least 64-bits).  Look for questions on SO (or [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)) about password hashing.

Comment: Really thanks for your long explanation. It helped a lot . I should learn more about db soon . thanks again :D